How to get GPS, and Time data from image EXIF in android?
I have a task in adnroid (kotlin):
Get the EXIF data from images, like coordinates and time. This whole android developing is new to me, javascript and .NET was my prev stack.
So I make an object from some guide, for using the camera (AndroidView), and take some pictures. The problem is, when I try to get the coords its always null.
Here is the code:
object CameraFileUtils {
    fun takePicture(
        cameraController: CameraController,
        context: Context,
        executor: ExecutorService,
        onImageCaptured: (Uri) -> Unit,
        onError: (ImageCaptureException) -> Unit
    ) {

        val photoFile = createPhotoFile(context)
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        cameraController.takePicture(outputOptions,
            executor,
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile).let(onImageCaptured)
                    val savedUri = savePhotoToGallery(context, photoFile)
                    onImageCaptured(savedUri)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    onError(exception)
                }
            })
    }

    private fun savePhotoToGallery(context: Context, photoFile: File): Uri {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        val fileName = photoFileName()
        val newImageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            })
        val inputStream: InputStream? = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(photoFile))

        val exif = inputStream?.let { ExifInterface(it) }

        val latitude = exif?.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
        val longitude = exif?.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
        val dateTime = exif?.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)

        Log.d("Photo Info", "Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude, Date/Time: $dateTime")

        val outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(newImageUri!!)
        outputStream?.let {
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(photoFile)
            inputStream.copyTo(it)
            inputStream.close()
            it.close()
        }
        return newImageUri
    }

    private fun createPhotoFile(context: Context): File {
        val outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory(context)
        return File(outputDirectory, photoFileName()).apply {
            parentFile?.mkdirs()
        }
    }

    private fun photoFileName() =
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.UK).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"

    private fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
        return context.filesDir
    }
}

Can somebody help me with this? And some explanation?
How to save the coords in a variable? The coords is used for validating, and for route plan.
